# Youtube data API with NodeJS issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, youtube

I've just copied a simple example from Youtube docs but it fails.
I want to implement Youtube data API in my project.

Following these links:

[Youtube data api quickstart documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

[Youtube data api quickstart github repo](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/nodejs-quickstart.js)

1. I've created a new project in Google Developers Console
2. Added OAuth credentials
3. Downloaded my `"client_secret.json"` file
4. Copied [quickstart project](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/nodejs-quickstart.js) into my working folder

But when I run this script an error occurs:

**`~/workspace/youtube/quickstart $ node test-1.js`**

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/youtube/quickstart/test-1.js:31
   var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined
   at authorize (/home/ubuntu/workspace/youtube/quickstart/test-1.js:31:43)
   at processClientSecrets (/home/ubuntu/workspace/youtube/quickstart/test-1.js:20:3)
   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
```

Where did I possibly make a mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: Try debug the code. You can figure out what is happening. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the **client_secret**  json file. Try parsing the json using some online json parser. Since the parsing failed or could not find json file at the specificed location the ***credentials*** variable is *undefined*. Js engine throws error as it couldn't read *client_secret* of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you json file. If your json file start with `{web:{client...` you have chosen to create credentials for a Web application and this example won't work unless you change "installed" to "web"on your code.

The example is set to work perfectly if you choose to create credentials for a computer application. Then it will generate a json file with "installed".